# iOS: Small thumb in the native UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I'm using `UISwitch` in my `UIViewController` but I don't know how can I decrease the size of its `thumb`. I searched about it but I only find some libraries offering a switch with a big thumb. There is no attribute in the `storyboard` or the code that can help on doing this. So how can I have a small `thumb` of the native `iOS` `UISwitch`?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the thumb image of a `UISwitch`.

Check the [`UISwitch` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch) to see what properties are configurable.

If you want a switch with a different style, you can create your own custom `UIControl` subclass that behaves however you wish.

---

From a design perspective, there are only a small number of cases where it would be beneficial to have a custom switch. The `UISwitch` thumb image is relatively large to create the affordance that it can be "flipped".

The default `UISwitch` also contains some accessibility features that you will lose if you create a custom switch.

Comment: From a purely design perspective, a custom switch will always win over a default switch. What accessibility features are lost on custom switches?

Answer (score 1):

I found a great pod that solves this, and many other problems on GitHub.

This will allow you to create switches with custom sizes, shapes, and gives you a lot more power over customization.

I just installed the class into my project, rather than using pod install, as it is only a single file class, and as of this posting was not updated to Swift 4.2.

In order to use it with Storyboards, I added a UIView of the shape and size I wanted the switch, and then added the my custom switch to the UIView.

Link to the GitHub source below. Note this is not my repo, it was just something I came across.

https://github.com/bvogelzang/SevenSwitch